# How to clip `xarray.DataArray` across a dimension?

Tags: python-xarray

I have an N-dimensional `xarray.DataArray` `x` and I would like to cap the values to a quantiles across `i`.

For example, in pandas a similar operation would look like this:

```
xlow = x.quantile(0.99,axis=0)
xhigh = x.quantile(0.99,axis=0)
x_capped = x1.clip(lower=xlow, upper=xhigh)
```

Does `xarray` have an equivalent way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you want to replace values based on the quantile over the whole dataset or at the specified location?

e.g. if I have a dataarray containing temperatures for the US, do I replace a value in Washington if it's higher than the 99th quantile over the whole US? Or if it's higher than the 99th of temperature in Washington?

Comment: Capping temperature of Washington by "its" quantile over the time index (and doing it for all other cities in a vectorised way (no for loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xarray.DataArray.clip`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.clip.html), which works in much the same way:

```py
clipped = da.clip(
    min=da.quantile(0.01, dim='time'),
    max=da.quantile(0.99, dim='time'),
)
```