# How to clip multiple points at specific (varying) timesteps in a 3D Array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, point, python-xarray, clip

I want to clip a multidimensional array with points (shapefile). The points are specific events and have a lat, lon and time value. I lcreate from the columns of the shapefile: lat, lon and time a list (for each), to then in a next step select/clip with these lists the multidimensional array (using the function xarray .sel):

```
lons = pts.geometry.x.to_list()
lats = pts.geometry.y.to_list()
time = pts.time.to_list()

values_pts = 3D_array.sel(lon=lons, lat=lats, time=time, method="nearest")
```

With this split of the lat, lon, time to separated lists, they lose their relation to one another, which means that all points are cut out for each timestep and not for the specific dates they occured ..
Do you have any ideas how I could clip the lat and lon at the specific timesteps in a 3D array?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I have added two tags for you that I think are important. Please check if I did this correctly! Please read [ask]. For clipping please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616306/18667225

Comment: thanks so much for adding those tags @Markus! would never have found this q without the python-xarray tag. cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @markus for adding the tag and the links - I am new to stackoverflow so I am still in the process of understanding how everything works!

Comment: @Blue_Green the key to using tags when asking a question is to try to identify the topic of the question in a way that attracts users who would be able to answer questions on that topic. So in your list of tags, `[python]` and `[python-xarray]` are helpful because they'll flag the question for experts in those areas. `[point]`, `[clip]`, and `[multidimensional-array]` on the other hand are more meta-tags - it's unlikely anyone is going to be looking for all questions about points independent of language :). See the help center guide to [tagging](/help/tagging) for more info.

Comment: one of the keys to asking on SO is understanding what it's like for an *answerer* too - [right now there are over 7 million unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) on this site! so you're more likely to get a good answer if you help us help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than converting x, y, and time to a list, convert them to an `xarray.DataArray` using [`pd.Series.to_xarray()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_xarray.html). This allows you to make use of xarray's [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) mode, where you don't just filter the `(lat, lon, time)` dimensions you actually reshape the array to conform to the index of the selectors. The following will reshape the lat, lon, and time dimensions to pull the points you request out of the array, maintaining their relationship to each other and setting a new dimension matching the index of your dataframe:

```py
lons = pts.geometry.x.to_xarray()
lats = pts.geometry.y.to_xarray()
time = pts.time.to_xarray()

# because lons, lats, and time all have the same indexing 
# dim, which is the the index of `pts`, the following will
# pull the points you're requesting out of the array and 
# reshape them into a 1-D vector indexed by the common
# indexing dimension
values_pts = 3D_array.sel(
    lon=lons, lat=lats, time=time, method="nearest"
)

# you could now convert this back to a pandas.Series 
# (if 3D_array is a DataArray) or pandas.DataFrame
# (if it's a Dataset) if desired:
values_pts.to_series()
```